# Multiple outcomes if the condition is met in looker studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a dataset with different outcomes like 'Applied', 'Graduated', 'Inelgible','Waitlist', 'On-boarded'  I want to create a quarterly trend line in google data studio that shows three separate lines 'Applied' -> with all the rows in the dataset irrespective of the outcome, Ineligible where the outcome is Ineligible and Waitlist where the outcome is waitlist

```
Date         Outcome
20-01-2022   Applied
21-03-2022   Graduated
22-03-2022   Waitlist
23-09-2022   Waitlist
21-01-2023   Ineligible
```

So the outcome should have three seperate trend lines one for Applied where say for quarter 1 it should have 3 record count where as the Waitlist trend line should have one record count.

I have tried creating a case formula but it obviously prints just one trend line 'Applied'

```
CASE WHEN Applicant
Outcome IN ("Applied","Ineligible","Waitlist","On-boarded","Graduated","Dropped-out") THEN "Applied"
WHEN Applicant
Outcome IN ("Ineligible") THEN "Ineligible"
WHEN Applicant
Outcome IN ("Waitlist") THEN "Waitlist" 
ELSE "OTHER"
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `REGEX_MATCH()` function along with your case. That way you can leverage multiple values in your `Outcome` column:

```
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Outcome,"(Applied|On-boarded|Graduated|Dropped-out)") then "Applied"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Outcome,"Ineligible") then "Ineligible"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Outcome,"Waitlist") then "Waitlist"
ELSE "Other"
END
```

From there you should be able to use the new dimension to count the number of instances for each for your trend line.